# Cambiar estilo de tabs en TabbedPage en Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

He estado intentando cambiar el estilo (Fondo de color, color de letras e indicador) de los tabs en `Xamarin.Forms`, he intentado hacer mi propio **custom render** pero parece que no funciona.

Lo que si funciona es [cambiar los colores por XML](https://blog.xamarin.com/material-design-for-your-xamarin-forms-android-apps/), pero cuando lo hago **rompe todo el estilo que tenia en el proyecto compartido** de `Xamarin.Forms`.

Alguien sabe la forma correcta de cambiar (*por lo menos*) el fondo de color de los tabs en un TabbedPage desde:

1. Xamarin.Forms (Desde el **Shared project**, **no XML**)
2. XML (Solo si hubiera una forma de **cambiar solamente el estilo de los Tabs** sin tocar ningun otro estilo )

Llevo días tratando de hacerlo pero no he podido, creo que a estas alturas ya estoy bloqueado.

Comment: Utilizas xaml o lo haces todo con C#?

Comment: En ese entonces utilizaba C# para todo

Answer (score 0):

Puedes modificar directamente el recurso `Tabbar.axml` dentro de Resources > layout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    style="@style/MyTabLayout"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

Allí están las propiedades `app:tabIndicatorColor` y `android:background`.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes indicar esas características de los estilos en el XAML de la siguiente forma:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            x:Class="MyApp.Views.MainPage"
            xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"

            android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
            android:TabbedPage.BarBackgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:TabbedPage.BarTextColor="#20ce88"
            android:TabbedPage.BarItemColor="#575a6a"
            android:TabbedPage.BarSelectedItemColor="#20ce88" >
```

Las propiedades que comienzan por `android:TabbedPage` son las que se encargan de dar estilo en android y esos mismos estilos los puedes aplicar en iOS en el archivo .cs